# How to center horizontal recyclerview in center?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I make horizontal recyclerview in the center?

I have tried many ways putting `android:layout_gravity="center"` in recyclerView or putting recyclerview in linear layout.

But I didn't succeed.

This is my code.

This is xml file which contains my recyclerview.

```
    <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="horizontal">
   
       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:visibility="invisible"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
           android:id="@+id/recycler_view">
       </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
   
   </LinearLayout>
```

**item_row.xml file**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textview_size"
            android:background="@drawable/textview_border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            />
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: just change the LinearLayout width to match_parent in item_row.xml and layout_gravity to gravity

Answer (score 9):

You have to set the Recyleview's layout width to : wrap_content
This one should work :

```
         <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                >
```

Comment: doesnt work inside ConstraintLayouts

Answer (score 3):

3 years later but I hope my answer helps another dev.

In the parent of the element xml:

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

then set your child views to be a specific width

```
        android:layout_width="300dp"
```

And don't forget to add:

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" //If you're using constraint layout as parentw
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

Answer (score 2):

use `RelativeLayout` insted of `LinearLayout` than
use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` of your `RelativeLayout` like this

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `android:gravity="center"` to `LinearLayout` Which contain your `RecyclerView` .

Answer (score 0):

Use android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" in your linear layout

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view">
      </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just updated recyclerview version in gradle file and it worked now!

:)

Please update version of a library in gradle file OR to further :

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding

```
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
```

and

```
android: layout_weight = "1"
```

to the recyclerview item xml worked.